# Conditional Expectation involving $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, variance

let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\ X : \ \Omega \ \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ $  a real random variable with respect to $\mathcal{F}$ with

$$\mathbb{E}(X^2)<{\infty}$$
Let $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. We introduce 
     $$Y= \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}], \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Z=\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2|\mathcal{G}]$$
We recall that $Y\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{G},\mathbb{P})$ so that both $Y$ and $Z$ are well defined.

1. Prove that $\mathbb{E}(Z)= \mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}(Y^2)$
2. Deduce from this that the variance of $X$ satisfies
   $$Var(X) = Var(Y)+\mathbb{E}(Z)$$
   Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: 1. done… 2. done… and now? What have you done so far, what are your questions?

Comment: You may want to read the [guide for asking good questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The summary of this is that you should tell us the work you've put into the problem so we can help.

Comment: Hi there. Sorry for that, I will upload what I've done so far. The problem is I don't know where to start, since $X$ and $Z$ are not G-Measurable, and the text of the exercise does not even specify if they are F-Measurable. It only specifies that the r.v are well defined. That is what I wanted to be clarified. Since I don't know how to start, I was waiting for an answer.

Comment: How is the homework outsourcing going? Not badly, it seems. Yet many homework questions to make others solve for you?

Comment: I'm sorry. This is my first time in a forum of this kind. I wasn't expecting to displease somebody or to violate some rule of the forum. I'm just looking for some help. Do you know some book with solved exercises of this kind? I'm studying statistical inference, simulation, measure theory, continuous-time finance, martingales. If you can help me, I will probably be able and happy to help somebody else in the future.

Comment: And the prize for the nastiest welcome goes to... I guess it's a tie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's observe first that $E(Y) = E(X)$ by the tower property, and hence
$$
V(X) - V(Y) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 - E(Y^2) + E(Y)^2 = E(X^2) - E(Y^2).
$$
Thus we have shown that (1.) and (2.) are equivalent, so it suffices to prove just one of them. We'll prove (1.)

Let us simply take the expectation of $Z$ and see that happens. As you rightly observe, $X$ *is not* $\mathcal{G}$-measurable but (by definition of conditional expectation) $Y$ *is*. Hence we have
$$
\begin{align*}
E(Z) 
&= E( E( X^2 + Y^2 - 2 X Y \mid \mathcal{G}) ) \\
&= E(E(X^2 \mid \mathcal{G})) + E(E(Y^2 \mid \mathcal{G})) - 2 E(Y E(X \mid \mathcal{G})) \\
&= E(X^2) + E(Y^2) - 2 E(Y^2) \\
&= E(X^2) - E(Y^2),
\end{align*}
$$
since $Y = E(X \mid \mathcal{G})$, by definition.

I agree that (2.) is a pretty scary looking equation (personally I don't like working with variances as much as expectations), but given the explicit form of $Z$ one really just needs to have the courage to bash out some algebra and hope for the best -- in this case our hope was fulfilled!

Comment: Drive-by -1 -- care to comment on how you feel my answer could be improved?